# FormControl change to FormControlName in formGroup

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

my code was:

```html
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
    <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">
        {{topping}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
                
  <mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of toppings.value" removable (removed)="onToppingRemoved(item)">
      {{item}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
```

I would like to merge `FormControl` into `FormGroup`. It will to be:

```html
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName ="toppings" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">
       {{topping}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
                
  <mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of toppings.value" removable (removed)="onToppingRemoved(item)">
      {{item}}
     <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
   </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
```

but always report error

> TS2339: Property 'toppings' does not exist on type 'testComponent'.
> <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of toppings.value" removable
> (removed)="onToppingRemoved(item)">

how to fix this or some points? thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this typo in your real code as well? `<mat-select formControl]Name ="toppings" multiple>`

Comment: Yes. it's sample what i foud from google. It's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**formControlName** directive just need the name of your formControl as it retrieves it thanks to the parent **formGroup** diretive placed on your `<form>`.

But outside of this context, using `toppings` means you have a *toppings* property declared into your component.

To fix it you need to retrieve the formcontrol from your form to get its value.

For example if the structure of your form is :

```
form = new FormGroup({
 toppings: new FormControl()
});
```

you can retrieve the formcontrol value this way into your component :

```
<mat-chip *ngFor="let item of form.get('toppings').value"></mat-chip>
```

Comment: i had define :  form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    toppings: [{ value: '' }],
  }); in my testComponent.ts. Is it wrong way?

Comment: move your form to : `form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({ toppings: [], });` as you don't need nested **value**.